# Using Lo-Dash and Underscore simulatenously in RequireJS environment

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js, amd, lodash

In a RequireJS environment, what's the best way to allow some AMD modules to use Lo-Dash while others simultaneously use Underscore?

Comment: Lo-dash should be a drop-in replacement for Underscore (but not the other way around) so why don't you just use Lo-dash?

Comment: I have legacy modules that aren't compatible with Lo-Dash that need to run simultaneously with newer modules that use Lo-Dash. Refactoring and testing the older modules is not currently possible.

Comment: . . . And contrary to popular belief and claims, Lo-Dash is not a perfect drop-in replacement for Underscore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself fairly simply. Specifically use the `lodash` path for modules that require Lo-Dash and `underscore` for modules that require "underscore":

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'underscore': 'path-to-my-underscore-file',
    'lodash': 'path-to-my-lodash-file'
  }
});
```

In this way, the two libraries can be used simultaneously without any interference.

Contrary to popular belief and claims, Lo-Dash is not a *perfect* drop-in replacement for Underscore.

Comment: I'm not sure who has been claiming Lo-Dash is the perfect drop-in replacement for Underscore aside for MAYBE Lo-Dash?

Comment: The number of up-votes on this question's first comment indicate the common misconception. It's probably assumed because both Underscore and Lo-Dash use the "_" global.

Answer (score 5):

The pathing solution you already mentioned is an option (I think the better one). I know of an alternative way, but I don't necessarily think it is better since it is more deceptive. You could remap what "lodash" and "underscore" mean for various packages.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'path-to-my-underscore-file',
        'lodash': 'path-to-my-lodash-file'
    },
    map: {
        'some/lodash_compatible_module': {
            'underscore': 'lodash'
        },
        'some/lodash_compatible_folder': {
            'underscore': 'lodash'
        },
        'some/oldmodule_or_folder': {
            'underscore': 'underscore'
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to create a facade you could also do something like this as well:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        utils: 'lodash',
        'underscore': 'path-to-my-underscore-file',
        'lodash': 'path-to-my-lodash-file'
    },
    map: {
        'some/lodash_compatible_module': {
            'utils': 'lodash'
        },
        'some/lodash_compatible_folder': {
            'utils': 'lodash'
        },
        'some/oldmodule_or_folder': {
            'utils': 'underscore'
        }
    }
});
```

While there are some negatives with this approach. There are some cool things. Namely being able to remap what third party dependencies may think a package is (if that is a problem).

For more info on how map works check out: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map

Comment: Very interesting wiring!